# Jinja2 syntax issues when using inline styling for HTML

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am passing a randomly generated value from my backend python to my html template

```
card_heights = [random(300, 340) for _ in range(len(games_list))]

return render_template('search_results.html', list=list, platform_to_image=platform_to_image,card_heights=card_heights)
```

The issue is Jinja2 is saying it is expecting a property value and a selector and expects a "{" for the code to work.
I looked at the documentation for Jinja and honestly can't see what I am doing wrong in this code.

```
<div class="card h-100 m-2" style="border-radius: 13px; width: 304.8px; height: {{ card_heights }}px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a list instead of a single value for height.
The CSS height property takes only a single value.